# JQuery pushing object into array overwrites all array objects

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to push an object into an array using key 'name' from a form input. I get the information from the form fine and log the object.name & id. Its on the following entries from the input that overwrite the previous object values. 
How am I overwriting all the object values here? 
Thanks!

```
        let inputValues = [];
        let newTodoInput = {};
        let idNumber = 0;

        function bindEvents() {
            $('form').on('submit', function() {
                event.preventDefault();
                newTodoInput.name = $('.new-todo').val(); // obj
                newTodoInput.id = idNumber++;
                inputValues.push(newTodoInput);

                $('form').trigger("reset"); // clear form
            });
        }
```

first entry in array

```
0:Object
id:1
name:"1st entry"
```

second entry for array

```
0:Object
id:1
name:"2nd entry"

1:Object
id:1
name:"2nd entry"
```

Comment: you're not creating new objects, you just keep changing the same object and inserting the same object into your array. `inputValues[0] === inputValues[1]`. `let newTodoInput = {};` is unneccesary outside the event handler, it should be inside. Additionally, `idNumber` can be replaced with `inputValues.length + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `let newTodoInput = {}` inside your event handler. The problem is that you are creating a single reference to the object, updating it, and pushing a reference to that object into the array. Let me be very clear -- **You are not pushing an instance of that object, you are pushing a *reference* to that object** onto the array. So the next time it gets triggered, you update the name and id properties, which updates the original object, which gets reflected by every array element that references the object.

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var newTodoInput = {}; // <-- This is the key to this working properly
  newTodoInput.name = $('.new-todo').val(); // obj
  newTodoInput.id = idNumber++;
  inputValues.push(newTodoInput);

  $('form').trigger("reset"); // clear form
});
```

Comment: thank you for the clarification on pushing the instance / reference. I understand my issue now. thank you & @Kevin B

Comment: @JackZ You're welcome! Glad that helped clarify your issue